# How to use NULLIF with OPENJSON to replace empty strings?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am trying to read from a JSON string, but where empty values exist I need to replace with NULL in SQL.  I have tried NULLIF, but get a syntax error.  Examples online seems to only deal with replacing JSON values when writing back to JSON, rather than reading it.

```
SELECT 
    js.*
INTO
    #StringValues
FROM 
    OPENJSON (@myJsonString, N'$') WITH (
         Foo nvarchar(50) N'$.Foo '
        ,Bar nvarchar(250) NULLIF(N'$.Bar', N'') -- Syntax error
    ) AS js
```

Is it possible to create null values when reading from JSON?

Comment: Do it in your `SELECT`, not the `WITH`. If you didn't use `SELECT *` this would be trivial.

Comment: Note that JSON supports `NULL` values as well. If you have JSON and want `""` to be `NULL` values then really you should be defining them as `Null` in your JSON.

Comment: Yes totally agree.  This is coming from an external source so I can't control the empty values, even though they aren't supposed to exist.

Comment: Doing in `SELECT` as you advise works great, thank you.  Please migrate to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @dataJSON=(SELECT REPLACE(@dataJSON, '""','null' ));
```

After this use your `nullif` or any other logic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).